# How to change localDb connection String to SQL Server for Linux deployment?

Tags: asp.net-core, connection-string

I am beginner and trying to deploy my first app on linux server but localDB isn't supported. How I convert this localDB connection string to SQL Server. I searched and found only in xlm everywhere. Like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#Converting%20Connection%20Strings%20between%20LocalDB%20and%20SQL%20Server%20Express)

This is connection string in startup.cs file which I need to change.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        var connection = @"server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=BabluDatabaseChat;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        services.AddDbContext<MessageContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And what is the problem with the connections strings from the posted link?

Comment: Are you trying to configure the string to be a connection to SQL Server when the project is running in production environment on a Linux Server  ?

Comment: Sir @Nkosi nothing wrong with this connection string. But deploying it on Linux it says localDB isn't supported on this platform.

Comment: @itminus yes sir

Comment: @Abdullah_Libra7 , if in that case , you could create two configuration files named as `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json` . And modify the environment by setting `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` . Another way is to inject an instance of `IHostingEnvironment` to `Startup` , and then you can check the environment by `env.IsDevelopment()` ,`env.IsProduction()` or`env.IsEnvironment("your_env_string")` .

Comment: @Abdullah_Libra7 For more information , you can refer the [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/environments/sample/EnvironmentsSample) by Microsoft